# Get container of ag grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ag-grid

I have many ag-grid to handle. I want to get the container of the ag-grid I working with. How can I get the div contain the grid when I click on the grid?
I use a common option for all grid. when change selection I will do few thing with container but I don't know how to get the container.

```
var AgGridOptions = {
    context:  {
        $parent: null
    },
    columnDefs:  null,
    rowData:  [],
    enableSorting:  true,
    enableFilter:  false,
    groupSelectsChildren:  true,
    debug:  false,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
}
function getContainer() {
    var down = {},
        _this = this;
    //do sth
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Do you have some code we can have a look at? That would make it a lot easier to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add eventListener to your grid container, and get all parent nodes that you need.

```
document.querySelector('.ag-root-wrapper').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    //do something with event target
    console.log(event.target);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your ag-grid and see for a signature in the outermost DOM element of it.

I found the id to be `borderLayout_eRootPanel`.

So, you can look for this element and get it's parent.

```
var gridContainer = $('#borderLayout_eRootPanel').parent()
```